# IOS 6.0.1 UnTethered Jailbreak

Tags: ipad, ios, jailbreak

Is there an UnTethered Jailbreak for IPad 3 with IOS 6.0.1? I've been searching for a while but couldn't find one.

**UPD**

There are some [news](http://www.jailbreaknation.com/6.16.0.26.0.1-untethered-jailbreak-for-iphone-5-achieved) on the topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great news! Jailbreak is now [available](http://evasi0n.com/)

Answer (score 6):

Currently there is no jailbreak for devices with A5, A5X A6, or A6X chips; Tethered or Untethered. This means we need to be patient for the Chronic Dev Team to complete the jailbreak for the IPhone 4S, 5, IPad 2, 3, 4 and Mini. Do not be fooled by any site that *aims* to have it available. Most of them charge and may actually be viruses.

Check http://www.redmondpie.com for any updates. They will have realtime updates as to the status of the progress / release.